# Error switching between activity and map fragment activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I currently have a working Google Maps screen, and I'm trying to add in additional functionality.

On map click, I want to open up a new activity to create a new marker. When I hit create, I want to go back to the map.

The issue I'm running into is a runtime error, through googling I figured out that I need to somehow destroy the previous map fragment in order to reinstantiate another one. This is the part I am struggling with: How do I either destroy a map fragment or re-load the map fragment on create?

Code:

```
public class MapsMain extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {


//Initializing variables
private GoogleMap myMap;
boolean locationPermissionGranted;
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
private Location mLastKnownLocation;
private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
private static final String TAG = MapsMain.class.getSimpleName();
private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085);
private AlertDialog.Builder userPrompt;
private AlertDialog.Builder markerInfo;
private String titleInput;
private String descInput;
private ArrayList<MapItem> markerArray = new ArrayList<>();
private MapItem tryMarker;
private MapItem putMarker;

private Button button;
private TextView myTextView;
private ImageView mainImage;
private TextView instructionTextView;
private TextView functionTextView;

private Button cameraButton;
private EditText titleEdit;
private EditText descriptionEdit;
private Button scenicButton;
private Button shadyButton;
private Button coveredButton;
private Button workButton;
private Button createButton;
private Button cancelButton;

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
ImageView mImageView;
private int markerCounter = 0;
String tempImg = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_main);

    editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

    mainImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //accessing image
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);    //accessing button
    myTextView = findViewById(R.id.TitleText); //accessing caption
    instructionTextView = findViewById(R.id.instructionText);
    functionTextView = findViewById(R.id.functionsText);

    button.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
        setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment);

        // Grab SupportMapFragment and async data call when it's ready
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    });

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    myMap = googleMap;

    //pull shared preferences HERE

    //Turn on My Location layer then get user location
    getLocationPermission();
    updateLocationUI();
    getDeviceLocation();
    myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sampleImg);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        tempImg = encodeToBase64(imageBitmap);
    }
}


//Defining MapItem Object
public class MapItem {
    String title = "";
    String description = "";
    LatLng coords;
    String base64Img;
    String additionalInfo;

    //constructor 1, temporary, ideally only use the second constructor in the future
    public MapItem(LatLng coords) {
        this.coords = coords;
    }

    //second constructor, after button issue, can get worked out.

    public LatLng getCoords() {
        return this.coords;
    }

    public void setTitle(String t) {
        this.title = t;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String d) {
        this.description = d;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setIsShady() {
        this.additionalInfo = this.additionalInfo + "\n This bench is shady!";
    }

    public void setIsScenic() {
        this.additionalInfo = this.additionalInfo + "\n This bench is scenic!";
    }

    public void setIsCovered() {
        this.additionalInfo = this.additionalInfo + " \n Safe from the elements";
    }

    public void setWorkBench() {
        this.additionalInfo = this.additionalInfo + "\n Good place to do work";
    }

    public void setAdditionalInfo() {
        this.description = this.description + this.additionalInfo;
    }

    public void setBase64Img(String s) {
        this.base64Img = s;
    }

    public String getBase64Img() {
        return this.base64Img;
    }

}

public void populateMap() {
    if (markerArray.size() == 0) {
        int tempCounter = 0;
        while (true) {

        }
    }
    for (MapItem g: markerArray) {
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(g.coords));
    }
}


private void getLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationPermissionGranted = true;
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    locationPermissionGranted = false;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationPermissionGranted = true;

        }
    }
    updateLocationUI();
}

private void updateLocationUI() {
    if (myMap == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (locationPermissionGranted) {
            myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            //Google Maps API documentation says this line is necessary
            //but variable type not specified
            //myLastKnownLocation = null;
        }
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void getDeviceLocation() {
    //this function gets most recent device location, which is rare when location != available
    try {
        if (locationPermissionGranted) {
            //android error suggestion is handled already, suppress.
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Task locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //set map camera to current position
                        mLastKnownLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM
                        ));
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No current location. Set default");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                        myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                        myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch(SecurityException e) {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}


@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    //on click this creates new marker using MapItem's base constructor, to get coordinate data into the AlertDialog UI
    setContentView(R.layout.relative_create_popup);
    createMarker(point);
    //calls user prompt method
    //promptUser();

}

public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap myImage = image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return imageEncoded;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

This is the part that is generating errors: when I call createMarker, I pull up fields that the user can put text into. When I set the `onClickListener()` for the submit button, the app crashes.

```
public void createMarker(LatLng coords) {
    String tempTitle;
    String tempDescription;

    MapItem tempMapItem = new MapItem(coords);


    cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
    titleEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEdit);
    descriptionEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionEdit);
    scenicButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scenicButton);
    shadyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shadyButton);
    coveredButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.coveredButton);
    workButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.workButton);
    createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createButton);
    cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);


    cameraButton.setOnClickListener((camera) -> {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        tempMapItem.setBase64Img(tempImg);
    });


    tempMapItem.setTitle(titleEdit.getText().toString());
    tempMapItem.setDescription(descriptionEdit.getText().toString());


    scenicButton.setOnClickListener((scenic) -> {
        tempMapItem.setIsScenic();
        scenicButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    });

    shadyButton.setOnClickListener((shady) -> {
        tempMapItem.setIsShady();
        shadyButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    });

    coveredButton.setOnClickListener((covered) -> {
        tempMapItem.setIsCovered();
        coveredButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    });

    workButton.setOnClickListener((work) -> {
        tempMapItem.setWorkBench();
        workButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    });

    createButton.setOnClickListener((create) -> {
        //tempMapItem.setAdditionalInfo();
        //markerArray.add(tempMapItem);
        //editor.putString("title"+markerCounter, tempMapItem.getTitle());
        //editor.putString("description"+markerCounter, tempMapItem.getDescription());
        //editor.putFloat("latitude"+markerCounter, (float) coords.latitude);
        //editor.putFloat("longitude"+markerCounter, (float) coords.longitude);
        //editor.putString("image"+markerCounter, tempMapItem.getBase64Img());
        //populateMap();

        setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment);

        // Grab SupportMapFragment and async data call when it's ready
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    });


}
```

More code

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    //For testing; long click clears map, next marker input will re-populate fully!
    createMarker(point);
    myMap.clear();
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}



@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    setContentView(R.layout.view_popup);
    String tempTitle ="";
    String tempDescription = "";
    for (MapItem g: markerArray) {
        double lat1 = g.getCoords().latitude;
        double long1= g.getCoords().longitude;
        double lat2 = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        double long2 = marker.getPosition().longitude;
        double threshold = .0005;
        if ((Math.abs(lat1-lat2) < threshold) && (Math.abs(long1-long2) < threshold)) {
            tempTitle = g.getTitle();
            tempDescription = g.getDescription();
        }
    }

    //markerZoom(marker, tempTitle, tempDescription);
    return false;
}
}
```

//The XML: create_popup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Access the camera" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cameraButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Bench Name: "
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/titleEdit"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleEdit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:text="Bench Description: "
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/descriptionEdit"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titleEdit"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titleEdit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionEdit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:text="Press the buttons below to add tags to your bench:"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scenicButton"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/coveredButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/coveredButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Scenic" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/shadyButton"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/scenicButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scenicButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/scenicButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scenicButton"
    android:text="Shady" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/coveredButton"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scenicButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:text="Covered" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/workButton"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/shadyButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/coveredButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/coveredButton"
    android:text="Good Work Station" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/createButton"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/workButton"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:text="Create"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/createButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/createButton"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/createButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/createButton"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:text="Cancel"
    />




</RelativeLayout>
```

XML map fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mylab_final.cisc181.finalproject.MapsMain" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/sampleImg"
android:visibility="invisible"
/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
12-04 08:04:12.429 26140-26140/com.mylab_final.cisc181.finalproject E/Zygote: v2
12-04 08:04:12.430 26140-26140/com.mylab_final.cisc181.finalproject E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
12-04 08:04:47.422 26140-26140/com.mylab_final.cisc181.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.mylab_final.cisc181.finalproject, PID: 26140
      android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.mylab_final.cisc181.finalproject/com.mylab_final.cisc181.finalproject.MapsMain} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4575)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4609)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap7(ActivityThread.java)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(
```

ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Comment: You want to create new `Marker` on Google map?

Comment: From a new activity page. So, on map click I open up a new activity page, and when I hit the "create" button then it creates a new Marker on the map. Yes . But the issue is that when I hit create, the app fails.

Comment: Show logcat. What is the exception?

Comment: Edited to show the logcat

Comment: `did not call through to super.onDestroy()`... Where's your onDestroy method that you didn't call super?

Comment: I did not know where / how to implement onDestroy() code. That is what I am seeking help with.